# Sidebar not rendering in angular Feature Module

Tags: angular, nebular

I'm trying to design a feature module, but the sidebar component doesn't render correctly in a module that is not the root module.

Here is an example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-y6syjf

What am I doing wrong.

Comment: I'm not familiar with nebular.  But why would you want multiple sidebars?  Generally I would expect that from your feature module you would try to interact with the root sidebar and not try to put another one on the page.

Comment: I know multiple sidebar's is probably uncommon, but for my application, I need one for a main menu that can disappear completely.  Then I need a sub-sidebar that acts as a drawer, I'm implementing a quick access toolbar.  Hope that helps.